# Apache2 Server not starting

Tags: apache2

I installed Apache 2 using:

```
sudo apt-get install Apache2
```

Then tried to start it with:

```
sudo service Apache2 start
```

But ended up with:

```
Failed to start Apache2.service: Unit Apache2.service not found.
```

Any help? Thx

Answer (score 16):

Remember that linux/unix is case-sensitive, so `apache2` is not the same as `Apache2`

Try

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Then it should start right after you install it

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

If stopped

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: My bad sorry. The service was active the whole time.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-224:~$ sudo service apache2 status
 * apache2 is not running
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-224:~$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                                                              (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.

Comment: @MonaJalal different issue i think (some other service like nginx using port 80), create another question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the upper_case letter being used on your command.

USE: sudo service apache2 status NOT: sudo service Apache2 status