# How do I install and start apache2

Tags: apache2

I am trying to install and run apache2.

So I did

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

And then tried to start it

```
sudo apache2
```

which was answered with

```
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
```

This is in fact true: there is no such file.

So I touched it:

```
sudo touch /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and tried again

```
sudo apache2
```

which is now answered by

```
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
```

Very probably, I should add something to the touched `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file. But I have no idea what.

So, I have at least three questions: is apache supposed to be started with `sudo apache`? And what is the minimal configuration that I have to put into the `apache2.conf` file? Is there a package that I can `apt-get install` with such a minimal configuration to work from there?

**Addendum** As per Tarunkant Gupta's comment, if I try to start apache with

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

I get

```
Failed to start apache2.service: Unit apache2.service not found.
```

As per Saragyal's answer: I don't have `/etc/apache2/sites-available` nor `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. The content of `/etc/apache2` is:

```
tree /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/
 ├── apache2.conf
 └── conf-available
    └── javascript-common.conf
```

(and `apache2.conf` stems from my `touch`ing it).

Comment: for starting apache2, you should write <code>sudo service apache2 start</code>

Comment: Does not work, either.

Comment: You can see the same problem in [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/781534/apache2-server-not-starting)

Comment: @TarunkantGupta: I used lowercase letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have Apache installed and functionally working, you don't need the `/etc/apache2` directory where all the configuration files are stored.

You also mentioned that you used `touch` to create an `apache.conf` file.  That is very problematic because there are defaults and settings that need to be specified in the `conf` file, which is missed by creating a blank file.

Apache will work when installed from the repository.  It will create all the necessary files and actually start the server when installed.

**Remove what you have, then perform a fresh install from the repository.**

Remove and purge the current installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 libapache2-mod-php
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 libapache2-mod-php
```

You may have to cycle through those two commands more than once.  It'll be clean when the last command's output resembles:

```
apollo@testnode2:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 libapache2-mod-php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libapache2-mod-php' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Now remove faulty configuration files that may not be overwritten in a fresh install.  Remove or rename the `/etc/apache2` folder:

```
$ sudo mv /etc/apache2/ /etc/apache2.old
```

**Now install Apache2 fresh with:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php
```

If you have settings from your old settings that you want to incorporate into the new installation, you can copy the difference to the new `/etc/apache2` directory.  Making step-by-step changes might help you to identify where you went wrong the first time.

**Put your site's configuration files into a VirtualHost**

Also, I recommend that you leave the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file intact.  Make a new virtual host file to contain your desired configuration.  Just copy the `000-default.conf` to a `mysite.conf` file, then enable this virtual host with the command:

```
$ sudo a2ensite mysite.conf
```

This way if there is a problem with your configuration file, you can just disable it with `a2dissite mysite.conf` while you fix it.  Apache won't be broken in the meantime.  You'll also retain the `000-default.conf` as a template for a working reference.

The key to a `virtualhost` configuraiton is the `ServerName` directive.  Accessing your site by that name will call that specific configuration.

**Starting, Stoping, and checking the Apache2 server**

You shouldn't try to start the Apache2 server by running the `/usr/bin/apache2` command.  The server should be started with a script to set all the needed variables.

You can `start`, `stop`, and check the `status` of the Apache2 server with one of these commands:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop apache2
$ sudo systemctl start apache2
$ sudo systemctl status apache2
```

Comment: Does `mysite.conf` go under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`, too? Can I use another name instead?

Comment: Yes.  For convenience call the `mysite` the name of what you want your site to be called when accessing it.  For instance, `apollo3.conf`... or anything else.  And yes... the `virtualhost` files goes in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder.

Comment: Apparantly, the first time I `apt-get installed apache2` something went wrong. This time, I seem to have all the needed files. Thanks for showing how to uninstall my previous broken installation.

Comment: Always a pleasure!

Comment: You may also need to edit /etc/hosts and add the name you set for `ServerName`, as well as setting the right Directory permissions in the .conf file, AND making the www-data group own your application files... See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts, https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246114/php-mkdir-permission-denied-problem (:

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that there is no apache2.conf file. Just google "default apache2.conf" and you should find a file on top. Just to confirm is there a chance you also dont have virtual sites. Check contents of directory /etc/apache2/sites-available and /etc/apache2/sites-enabled.

P.S. I couldn't comment.

Comment: This is what I think, too: there should be a minimal apache2.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

You install Apache using this command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
```

When the installation process is finished, Apache should be started automatically. Check whether your Apache server is running using this command:

```
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 status
```

If you see something like the following (specifically, the green circle indicating that the Apache is running), you're good to go:

[image]

Now, test it. Open up your web browser and navigate to the address `http://127.0.0.1:80`. If you see the Apache default page, your server is up and working.

To stop Apache, use this command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

To start Apache, use this command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: I don't have an `/etc/init.d/apache2` file (or script).

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger That's an indication that Apache2 isn't installed properly.